# Dropdown value change style of pages dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, kendo-ui

I am building a muti-page website with Kendo UI for Jquery.  I have a dropdown to select the style the user want. For now I can change the style, but it doesn't stick; as soon as I refresh the page it goes back to the default style. I want the style to also change for all the other pages.

Here is my code:
HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/kendo.default.min.css"/>
    <script src="script/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body  class="k-content">
<label for="theme">Theme:</label>
<input id="theme" name="theme">

<button class="k-button">Export Immagine</button>
<button class="k-button">Export Excel</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Jquery

```
$('#theme').kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: [
        { text: "Original", value: "default" },
        { text: "Black", value: "black" },
        { text: "Blue Opal", value: "blueopal" },
        { text: "Metro", value: "metro" },
        { text: "Silver", value: "silver" }
  ],
  dataTextField: "text",
  dataValueField: "value",
  change: function (e) {
    var theme = (this.value() || "default").toLowerCase();
    changeTheme(theme);  
}
});

// loads new stylesheet
function changeTheme(skinName, animate) {
    var doc = document,
        kendoLinks = $("link[href*='kendo.']", doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]),
        commonLink = kendoLinks.filter("[href*='kendo.common']"),
        skinLink = kendoLinks.filter(":not([href*='kendo.common'])"),
        href = location.href,
        skinRegex = /kendo\.\w+(\.min)?\.css/i,
        extension = skinLink.attr("rel") === "stylesheet" ? ".css" : ".less",
        url = commonLink.attr("href").replace(skinRegex, "kendo." + skinName + "$1" + extension);

        var theme = $('#theme').getKendoDropDownList().value();
    
        $('.k-chart').each(function () {
            var chart = $(this).data('kendoChart');
            chart.options.theme = skinName;
            chart.setOptions({ theme: theme });;
        });

    function preloadStylesheet(file, callback) {
        var element = $("<link rel='stylesheet' media='print' href='" + file + "'").appendTo("head");
        
        setTimeout(function () {
            callback();
            element.remove();
        }, 100);
    }

    function replaceTheme() {
        var oldSkinName = $(doc).data("kendoSkin"),
            newLink;

        if (kendo.support.browser.msie) {
            newLink = doc.createStyleSheet(url);
        } else {
            newLink = skinLink.eq(0).clone().attr("href", url);
            newLink.insertBefore(skinLink[0]);
        }
        
        skinLink.remove();

        $(doc.documentElement).removeClass("k-" + oldSkinName).addClass("k-" + skinName);

    }

    if (animate) {
        preloadStylesheet(url, replaceTheme);
    } else {
        replaceTheme();
    }
};
```

I know I have to use sessionStorage, but I don't really know how to implement that with Kendo. Can someone help me?

Comment: It doesn't matter what library you use. Session storage is separate. Perhaps your question should be on how to use session storage?

Comment: Better you can post your query in a separate thread here: https://www.telerik.com/forums

Comment: You need to persist the value chosen when it changes and when the page loads, get that value and set the dropdown to that value. You could store the value in localStorage, sessionStorage, a cookie or in a database. Depends on your needs and environment you have (for example session will survive a page reload but not browser restart). As it stands, your question is too broad to give a specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the session storage value inside the `changeTheme` function with the chosen theme name:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('user.theme', skinName);
```

Then check for it on page load, and set it if any value is set:

```
let userTheme = sessionStorage.getItem('user.theme');
  
if (userTheme) {
    changeTheme(userTheme);
    $('#theme').getKendoDropDownList().value(userTheme);
}
```

[Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/aREhuVuF)